# How many arrangements of the letters in the word CANADIAN do not contain a double N?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, factorial

I am stuck at this question. I came out with $\frac{8!}{3!\cdot2!}$, but the answer isn't correct. Thanks!

Comment: That's just counting **all** arrangements of CANADIAN. You need to eliminate those words with a double N.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be $$\frac{8!}{3!2!}-\frac{7!}{3!}$$

Comment: Any explanation of where these terms come from?

Comment: We just think about double $N$ like one letter.

Comment: why do we need to deduct the 7!/3!? thanks

Comment: @Jay Sun Because we need to kill cases with double $N$.